# Updating a field on list items based on the value selected from drop down "choice" column

Tags: c#, events, sharepoint-2010, workflow, splistitem

I have the following problem I have two list "TestUsers" amd "TestGroups". The "TestUsers" list has two columns [Group - Choice], [User - Single line of text]. The "TestGroups" list has two columns [Group - Single line of text], [CheckedOut - Single line of text].

The data in both lists are the following:

TestUsers (List): 
User: testuser1
Group: groupA

User: testuser2
Group: groupB

TestGroups (List):
Group: groupA
CheckedOut: testuser1

The requirement is that when a user in the "TestUsers" lists gets its "Group" changed for example from "groupA" to "groupB" than this should also be reflected and automatically updated in the "TestGroups" list. So for example in the "TestUsers" list if I were to change the "Group" for "testuser1" to "groupB" then in the "TestGroups" list the "Group" of "testuser1" has to also change/update to "groupB".

I hope the above is clear enough in describing what the requirement is.

I have tried doing this using worklflows and having lookup column as well as calculated columns. But both the calculated columns and the lookup columns does not seem to be work.

How would I go about achieving this using code in c#. I know how to update list items but what I am not sure is how to update listitems from a  list when a value is changed on a separate list as mentioned earlier.

I am stuck with this issue and thought I post it here so I can get some quick and accurate suggestions on how to procceed.

Many thanks, any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: r u doing in Event receiver or Workflow?

Comment: I was doing workflow, but I have been reading about event receivers but have not yet implemented it... Do you have any suggestion on this.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can try this In event receiver use `ItemUpdating` Event method just check it out item changed or not and create your logic

```
 public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemUpdated(properties);
        if (properties.ListTitle == "TestUsers")
        {
            SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb();
            SPList list = web.Lists[properties.ListTitle];
            SPListItem litemUser = list.GetItemById(properties.ListItemId);


            SPList objFeatureList = web.Lists["TestGroups"];
            SPQuery objParentQuery = new SPQuery();

            string user = properties.AfterProperties["User"].ToString();

            //in Caml query just find it out listitem which contain Users and than update its listitem.
            objParentQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Check_x0020_it_x0020_out'/><Value Type='Integer'>"+You should set Userid in Field From litemUser +"</Value></Eq></Where>";
            SPListItemCollection liitemcol = objFeatureList.GetItems(objParentQuery);
            foreach (SPListItem litemGroup in liitemcol)
            {
                litemGroup["Group"] = litemUser["Group"];
                litemGroup.Update();

                // or if you want to using Workflow just startWorflow when item has match over here.
            }

        }
    }
```